# Split Mailalerts module recipients in prestashop

Tags: php, module, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I need a specific list of recipients to receive stocks alerts only and another list of recipients to receive only the new order alert.

What is the best way to do it?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: What's your problem exactly? You will have to override this module and add a new field in database to store a second list of adresses. And adapt the piece of code that sends stock alert and order alert to use the right field. What did you try? We can only help you if you show us what you have done, we're not here to develop this functionality for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @FlorianLemaitre. 
To answer your question: i tried to duplicate the module and change to code so module 1 sends alert only for OOS and module 2 only for Orders.

Regarding the end of your message, I find it unpleasant. 
I don't ask people to develop functionality for me. Only how they would address this puzzle.
I am new to Prestashop and just want to be efficient.
Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: The problem here is that many persons ask questions without even trying to find an answer on their own. And from what I can read in your question, nothing tells me that you already tried something. You should have add in your question what you have tried and from this we would have tell you if you were taking the right path. Even if your code doesn't work and if you're not proud of it, you need to show that you have tried something on your own that doesn't work. Otherwise we have the sentiment to be working for free for you and not to be helping you.

Comment: I do understand your concern and obviously I tried several things as duplicating the module files itself and rename it to create two module and active only stock alert on one and orders confirmation on the other one.

Anyhow I will be way more specific next time! Thanks a lot for your time @FlorianLemaitre

Comment: I admit that my first response seemed a bit aggressive ;). Did you found any Helpful information in my answer bellow? If you need more information don't hesitate to post your concerns under it. Otherwise I invite you to accept it to mark this thread as solved. [how does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would deal with this question:

Create the override file `/override/modules/mailalerts/mailalerts.php` with this code:

```php
<?php

class MailAlertsOverride extends MailAlerts
{
    protected $merchant_mails_stock;

    protected function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        $this->merchant_mails_stock = str_replace(',', self::__MA_MAIL_DELIMITOR__, (string)Configuration::get('MA_MERCHANT_MAILS_STOCK'));
    }

    public function install($delete_params = true)
    {
        if (! parent::install($delete_params))
            return false;

        if ($delete_params)
        {
            Configuration::updateValue('MA_MERCHANT_MAILS_STOCK', Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_EMAIL'));
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function uninstall($delete_params = true)
    {
        if ($delete_params)
        {
            Configuration::deleteByName('MA_MERCHANT_MAILS_STOCK');
        }

        return parent::uninstall();
    }

    protected function postProcess()
    {
        $errors = array();

        if (Tools::isSubmit('submitMAMerchant'))
        {
            $emails = (string)Tools::getValue('MA_MERCHANT_MAILS_STOCK');

            if (!$emails || empty($emails))
                $errors[] = $this->l('Please type one (or more) e-mail address');
            else
            {
                $emails = str_replace(',', self::__MA_MAIL_DELIMITOR__, $emails);
                $emails = explode(self::__MA_MAIL_DELIMITOR__, $emails);
                foreach ($emails as $k => $email)
                {
                    $email = trim($email);
                    if (!empty($email) && !Validate::isEmail($email))
                    {
                        $errors[] = $this->l('Invalid e-mail:').' '.Tools::safeOutput($email);
                        break;
                    }
                    elseif (!empty($email) && count($email) > 0)
                        $emails[$k] = $email;
                    else
                        unset($emails[$k]);
                }

                $emails = implode(self::__MA_MAIL_DELIMITOR__, $emails);

                if (!Configuration::updateValue('MA_MERCHANT_MAILS_STOCK', (string)$emails))
                    $errors[] = $this->l('Cannot update settings');
            }
        }

        if (count($errors) > 0)
        {
            $this->html .= $this->displayError(implode('<br />', $errors));
            return $this->init();
        }

        parent::postProcess();
    }

    public function hookActionUpdateQuantity($params)
    {
        $this->merchant_mails = $this->merchant_mails_stock;
        parent::hookActionUpdateQuantity($params);
    }

    public function renderForm()
    {
        $fields_form_1 = array(
            'form' => array(
                'legend' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('Customer notifications'),
                    'icon' => 'icon-cogs'
                ),
                'input' => array(
                    array(
                        'type' => 'switch',
                        'is_bool' => true, //retro compat 1.5
                        'label' => $this->l('Product availability'),
                        'name' => 'MA_CUSTOMER_QTY',
                        'desc' => $this->l('Gives the customer the option of receiving a notification when an out-of-stock product is available again.'),
                        'values' => array(
                            array(
                                'id' => 'active_on',
                                'value' => 1,
                                'label' => $this->l('Enabled')
                            ),
                            array(
                                'id' => 'active_off',
                                'value' => 0,
                                'label' => $this->l('Disabled')
                            )
                        ),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'type' => 'switch',
                        'is_bool' => true, //retro compat 1.5
                        'label' => $this->l('Order edit'),
                        'name' => 'MA_ORDER_EDIT',
                        'desc' => $this->l('Send a notification to the customer when an order is edited.'),
                        'values' => array(
                            array(
                                'id' => 'active_on',
                                'value' => 1,
                                'label' => $this->l('Enabled')
                            ),
                            array(
                                'id' => 'active_off',
                                'value' => 0,
                                'label' => $this->l('Disabled')
                            )
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                'submit' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('Save'),
                    'class' => 'btn btn-default pull-right',
                    'name' => 'submitMailAlert',
                )
            ),
        );

        $fields_form_2 = array(
            'form' => array(
                'legend' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('Merchant notifications'),
                    'icon' => 'icon-cogs'
                ),
                'input' => array(
                    array(
                        'type' => 'switch',
                        'is_bool' => true, //retro compat 1.5
                        'label' => $this->l('New order'),
                        'name' => 'MA_MERCHANT_ORDER',
                        'desc' => $this->l('Receive a notification when an order is placed.'),
                        'values' => array(
                            array(
                                'id' => 'active_on',
                                'value' => 1,
                                'label' => $this->l('Enabled')
                            ),
                            array(
                                'id' => 'active_off',
                                'value' => 0,
                                'label' => $this->l('Disabled')
                            )
                        ),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'type' => 'switch',
                        'is_bool' => true, //retro compat 1.5
                        'label' => $this->l('Out of stock'),
                        'name' => 'MA_MERCHANT_OOS',
                        'desc' => $this->l('Receive a notification if the available quantity of a product is below the following threshold.'),
                        'values' => array(
                            array(
                                'id' => 'active_on',
                                'value' => 1,
                                'label' => $this->l('Enabled')
                            ),
                            array(
                                'id' => 'active_off',
                                'value' => 0,
                                'label' => $this->l('Disabled')
                            )
                        ),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'label' => $this->l('Threshold'),
                        'name' => 'MA_LAST_QTIES',
                        'class' => 'fixed-width-xs',
                        'desc' => $this->l('Quantity for which a product is considered out of stock.'),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'type' => 'switch',
                        'is_bool' => true, //retro compat 1.5
                        'label' => $this->l('Coverage warning'),
                        'name' => 'MA_MERCHANT_COVERAGE',
                        'desc' => $this->l('Receive a notification when a product has insufficient coverage.'),
                        'values' => array(
                            array(
                                'id' => 'active_on',
                                'value' => 1,
                                'label' => $this->l('Enabled')
                            ),
                            array(
                                'id' => 'active_off',
                                'value' => 0,
                                'label' => $this->l('Disabled')
                            )
                        ),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'label' => $this->l('Coverage'),
                        'name' => 'MA_PRODUCT_COVERAGE',
                        'class' => 'fixed-width-xs',
                        'desc' => $this->l('Stock coverage, in days. Also, the stock coverage of a given product will be calculated based on this number.'),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'type' => 'switch',
                        'is_bool' => true, //retro compat 1.5
                        'label' => $this->l('Returns'),
                        'name' => 'MA_RETURN_SLIP',
                        'desc' => $this->l('Receive a notification when a customer requests a merchandise return.'),
                        'values' => array(
                            array(
                                'id' => 'active_on',
                                'value' => 1,
                                'label' => $this->l('Enabled')
                            ),
                            array(
                                'id' => 'active_off',
                                'value' => 0,
                                'label' => $this->l('Disabled')
                            )
                        ),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'type' => 'textarea',
                        'cols' => 36,
                        'rows' => 4,
                        'label' => $this->l('E-mail addresses'),
                        'name' => 'MA_MERCHANT_MAILS',
                        'desc' => $this->l('One e-mail address per line (e.g. bob@example.com).'),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'type' => 'textarea',
                        'cols' => 36,
                        'rows' => 4,
                        'label' => $this->l('E-mail stock addresses'),
                        'name' => 'MA_MERCHANT_MAILS_STOCK',
                        'desc' => $this->l('One e-mail address per line (e.g. bob@example.com).'),
                    ),
                ),
                'submit' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('Save'),
                    'class' => 'btn btn-default pull-right',
                    'name' => 'submitMAMerchant',
                )
            ),
        );

        $helper = new HelperForm();
        $helper->show_toolbar = false;
        $helper->table = $this->table;
        $lang = new Language((int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'));
        $helper->default_form_language = $lang->id;
        $helper->module = $this;
        $helper->allow_employee_form_lang = Configuration::get('PS_BO_ALLOW_EMPLOYEE_FORM_LANG') ? Configuration::get('PS_BO_ALLOW_EMPLOYEE_FORM_LANG') : 0;
        $helper->identifier = $this->identifier;
        $helper->submit_action = 'submitMailAlertConfiguration';
        $helper->currentIndex = $this->context->link->getAdminLink('AdminModules', false)
            .'&configure='.$this->name
            .'&tab_module='.$this->tab
            .'&module_name='.$this->name;
        $helper->token = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');
        $helper->tpl_vars = array(
            'fields_value' => $this->getConfigFieldsValues(),
            'languages' => $this->context->controller->getLanguages(),
            'id_language' => $this->context->language->id
        );

        return $helper->generateForm(array($fields_form_1, $fields_form_2));
    }

    public function getConfigFieldsValues()
    {
        $config = parent::getConfigFieldsValues();
        $config['MA_MERCHANT_MAILS_STOCK'] = Tools::getValue('MA_MERCHANT_MAILS_STOCK', Configuration::get('MA_MERCHANT_MAILS_STOCK'));
        return $config;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code has not been tested but the overall concept is here, you should adapt it to your special needs.